# How to get past the lack of trust?

Tags: management, colleagues, time-management, expectations

So I just started a job doing what I have been doing for 7 years, fronted react-redux development work and doing pretty good I might add, out of the ton of tickets this company put together, like 16 of them, I will be done with 3 of them by tomorrow.

Not all of those tickets are frontend related, some are backend.

I notice our backend guy is kind of still getting up to speed with setup, but it has become an issue in the perception of the owners that "we" are not up to speed. One of the owners went as far to say today, "I trust you", and you guys know, if someone has to say they trust you, that means they don't trust and vice versa, if I have to say "you can trust me", you know you can't.

So, my question is, how do I get past this nonsense? Just ignore the jibber jabber and just continue to produce? Round up the managers and have a heart to heart chat? How do I get past the "oh I trust you I trust you (NOT)" and into the, we are happy you are here, or thanks for getting this work out the door, or whatever that stage is where I can say "XYZ" and its golden, not sure what that looks like, sorry.

I know they had an expectation of having a ton of stuff done by Christmas, but the first week, we accomplished nothing, not because I did not want to, but because management said, this first week we have nothing for you. Week 2, they hired the backend guy, so still had no work for me, but yet I was resolving bugs that the frontend already came with, but those are not in their radar because its not the change requests they must do to make their millions, but it was work I did. Week 3, I was helping the backend guy get up to speed with the frontend and he was trying to help me set up the backend and in week 3 and 4, I was studying the code and learning what I working with and getting a heads up from the project management guy that work would soon come. Week 5 the work came and so far the backend guy is still struggling getting set up and I am already pretty much done with 3 out of 16 tickets that came at us that week.

I mean to me, the hold up has been on managements part, but how do I get past this stage which is really them panicking because they set expectations for themselves that are not accurrate before I came on board?

Comment: “One of the owners went as far to say today, "I trust you", and you guys know, if someone has to say they trust you, that means they don't trust and vice versa, if I have to say "you can trust me", you know you can't.” This is the most ridiculous attempt at 3D chess ever. Just roll with it! Work there and day after day you will get used to the place.

Comment: Anyone hiring "new guys" in November to get work done "by Christmas" is a failure in management. That might work for unskilled labor or trivial tasks, but not for any kind of complex software development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to get past the lack of trust?

Produce the work.

3 out of 16 tickets doesn't seem like much to those who don't know what is involved. But you haven't even been there 2 months yet, you're still proving yourself. So carry on doing the best you can, trust comes with time it's not a given.